# Is it possible to construct a vsts build variable from the value of another build variables?

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

We have a requirement to build the xamarin android app to multiple build configuration. And we have different KeyStore file to sing the apps from different build configuration. This means that at build time we need to pick the right keystore file and password. We have managed to reference the path to keystore file using string interpolation. With respect to password it is but tricky.

Consider below example

Multiple Build configuration
      Test
      Dev
      Prod
   Below build variables carries the password for respective Keystore file
      KeyStorePasswordTest
      KeyStorePasswordDev
      KeyStorePasswordProd

Now in the build variable section, we have defined another build variable with the value as below
      KeyStorePassword  ------- $("KeyStorePassword$(BuildConfiguration)")

```
where valid BuildConfiguration is Test, Dev & Prod.
```

Could someone help me with this? This could be done from a shell script but we wanted a secure solution so decided to use the VSTS build server features.

We are using TFS 2015 server and the build is run on Mac Mini build agent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **shell script task** to assign your password differently by different build configurations.

The shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$(echo "KeyStorePassword$BuildConfiguration")
if [ $temp = "KeyStorePasswordDev" ]
then
{ 
# what you want to set password
}
elif [ $temp = "KeyStorePasswordProd" ] 
then
{ 
# what you want to set password
}
elif [ $temp = "KeyStorePasswordTest" ] 
then
{ 
# what you want to set password
}
else 
{ echo "no such config or password" }
fi
```

Arguments in shell script task:

```
 "$(BuildConfiguration)" "$(KeyStorePasswordDev)" "$(KeyStorePasswordTest)" "$(KeyStorePasswordProd)"
```

**Note:**
Since `$(BuildConfiguration)` variable is usually defined as `debug` or `release`, you can name a different variable name instead.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Will give a try.

Comment: Can you set your password successfully by the shell script task now?